# uidatepicker time mode how i can add an element?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidatepicker

I have an uidatepicker setted in time mode, so it shows only hours from 00:00 to 23:59 . I wanna insert an element before the 00:00 something like "-- : --" , it must be the start values to detect when a user don't want to use the picker. There's a way to achive this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't to that, the UIDatePickerView doesn't allow access to its underlying UIPickerView, in order to do that you must create you custom version on to of UIPickerView.

Is it accessible for you just to show UILabel with that string or something like that ? If so, than that it only possible way to do that.